# Problema con instalación de Angular

Tags: angular

Quiero instalar angular cli y tengo un error con el prefijo -g, me dice que no se reconoce como comando interno o externo. El comando y error es:

El comando: `npm install -g @angular/cli`

> "CALL "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program
> Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" prefix -g" no se
> reconoce como un comando interno o externo, programa o archivo por
> lotes ejecutable. npm ERR! code ENOENT npm ERR! syscall spawn
> ;C:\Users\lauta\adb-fastboot\platform-tools npm ERR! path
> C:\Users\lauta\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@angular\cli npm ERR!
> errno -4058 npm ERR! enoent spawn
> ;C:\Users\lauta\adb-fastboot\platform-tools ENOENT npm ERR! enoent
> This is related to npm not being able to find a file. npm ERR! enoent
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
> C:\Users\lauta\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2022-01-04T02_45_45_197Z-debug.log

Comment: Esto es un problema de npm. Que versión estas utilizando y como lo instalaste? Para obtener la versión haz un `npm -v`.

Comment: Paso a paso como instalar Angular y crear un proyecto.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TE5LzcSyKWg

Comment: No es verdad, el error no es de npm. El error de güindios.

Comment: Mejor desinstala node e instálalo usando nvm, usa el que es para windows  https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows Ahí te dicen cómo configurar lo

Answer (score 0):

puedes añadir al path el directorio donde se encuentra node:

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs\
```

Reinicia el comando y vuelve poner npm -v

Answer (score 0):

Si es problema del path, trata de borrar la cache con

```
npm cache clean --force
```

y luego agrega el path, a tus variables de entorno, y trata de reinstalar el angular CLI

Comment: Checa este video, de como agregar las variables del entorno del sistema: [Video, variables de entorno del sistema](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2w6BAEy6xlA&ab_channel=Codeando)